# How to make an image cooldown script in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have been having some problems with my image cooldown script recently. It's intent, when it works, is to let users post images in between a set time limit, in order to prevent spamming. In Discord.JS v12, it was working perfectly. However, after installing v13.6, it does not do its job anymore. Here's the code.

[image]

On line 6, there is a line that excludes some channels from the cooldown. The rest of the channels in the server are subject to it though. I would appreciate some help with this code, as it is pretty important.

FYI: All intents have been enabled and listed in the index.js file. Everything else works, but not this script.

Here's the raw paste code, if you want to test the code out:

```
const talkedRecently = new Set(); 

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {

if (!message.guild) return;

if (message.author.bot) return;

if (!message.channel.type === 'dm') return;       

if (!message.channel.id === 'channel1' || 'channel2' || 'channel3' || 'channel4' || 'channel5' || 'channel6' || 'channel7' || 'channel8') {

if (message.attachments.size > 0) {

if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
            setTimeout(()=> message.delete(), 5000).catch(err => console.log(err))
             message.channel.send("You must wait 30 seconds before sending another attachment - " + message.author.username).then(msg => {
                setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 10000)
            }).catch(/*Your Error handling if the Message isn't returned, sent, etc.*/)
            
          }
        }

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 issues with this code.

1. You are strict-comparing boolean to a string, which of course... will always return false

```js
// DON'T DO THIS
if (!thing === 'one') {

// DO THIS
if (thing !== 'one') {
```

2. That's not how we compare multiple values in JS

```js
// DON'T DO THIS
if (thing === "one" || "two" || "three")

// DO THIS
if ([ "one", "two", "three" ].includes(thing)) {
```

3. The channel IDs must be changed, there are no channels IDs such as `channelN`
4. You are deleting the same message 2 times

```js
// Right here
setTimeout(()=> message.delete(), 5000).catch(err => console.log(err))
// ...
// And here
.then(msg => { setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 10000) }).catch(/*Your Error handling if the Message isn't returned, sent, etc.*/)
```

5. Your code is outdated and requires an update
   See the update guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html).